# How to target the last column in the table body to replace its value with a fixed value for every row?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Using Vue, I have displayed table with dynamic data pulled from external JSON.

I want to target the last column in the table body to replace its value with a fixed value for every row.

How would I do this?

Note that my script uses the initial value from the JSON data for that column to determine which class to put on that `td`.

Here is my code:

```js
var dataURL = 'inc/data.json.php'

Vue.component('demo-grid', {
  template: '#grid-template',
  replace: true,
  props: ['data', 'columns', 'filter-key'],
  data: function() {
    return {
      data: null,
      columns: null,
      sortKey: '',
      filterKey: '',
      reversed: {}
    }
  },
  compiled: function() {
    // initialize reverse state
    var self = this
    this.columns.forEach(function(key) {
      self.reversed.$add(key, false)
    })
  },
  methods: {
    sortBy: function(key) {
      this.sortKey = key
      this.reversed[key] = !this.reversed[key]
    }
  }
})

var demo = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    searchQuery: '',
    gridColumns: [...],
    gridData: []
  },
  ready: function() {
    this.fetchData()
  },
  methods: {
    fetchData: function() {
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
        self = this
      xhr.open('GET', programsURL)
      xhr.onload = function() {
        self.gridData = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)
      }
      xhr.send()
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th v-repeat="key: columns" v-on="click:sortBy(key)" v-class="active: sortKey == key">
        {{key | capitalize}}
        <span class="arrow" v-class="reversed[key] ? 'dsc' : 'asc'">
          </span>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr v-repeat="
        entry: data
        | filterBy filterKey
        | orderBy sortKey reversed[sortKey]">

      <!-- here is where I wish to target the 5th in this row to change its value -->

      <td v-repeat="key: columns" v-class="lvl-1 : entry[key] === '1', lvl-2 : entry[key] === '2', lvl-3 : entry[key] === '3'>
          {{entry[key]}}
        </td>


      </tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Compare the special `$index` property with the length of the array (or computed property), and then use a template fragment so you can switch out the `<td>`

```
<template v-repeat="column in columns">
    <td v-show="$index < columns.length-1">All other columns...</td>
    <td v-show="$index === columns.length-1">Last Column</td>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with:

```
<div v-if="$index === 4">
...
```